# Hough transform in matlab vs opencv cpp

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, hough-transform

I have the following image: 

 [image]

 When I use hough transform in MATLAB, I get 100% detection of circles.

I use the following code in MATLAB:

```
[centersDark, radiiDark] = imfindcircles(closed_pic,[Rmin Rmax],'ObjectPolarity','dark');
```

I use the following code in cpp:

```
cv::medianBlur(mat, mat, 5);    
cv::Mat grayMat;     
cv::cvtColor(mat, grayMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);     
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles1;     
cv::HoughCircles(grayMat, circles1, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, 30, 30, 0, 0);
```

Also when I try to run hough transforn in cpp on binary image, I don't get any detection. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the parameters also have a look to output of median blur if the output make sense as input for hough circles.  Your 20 parameters is min center distance.. When the circles are closer. Alg might fail. Also you are using 30,30 parameters which are looks like  thresholds passed to canny() edges detections and they are First and second threshold. Also same this is also problem for this thresholds.. 
If you dont undestand the parameters use example from documentation and update only clear parameters.. In this examples only last 2 Min and Max radius of object what you try to find..

```
 HoughCircles(gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
             2, gray->rows/4, 200, 100 );
```

Comment: hi...when you write 0 as max and min it is like you write dont care...
the same parameteres works on a different pic so i dont think that is the problem.

Comment: OK make sense. I update the post,  Code just say if there is 0 0 put max as max of(cols,rows) and min radius as 0